# Is it possible to have access to the parent local variable in an overridden method in php?

Tags: php

- I don't want to declare static variables or class constants because
  in the example `$v` is prone to change.
- I don't want to pass through `return` statement.

Is there a mechanism for such a behavior to be implemented ?

---

[image]

Comment: If the parent method doesn't return the value, then no, there's no way to access `$v` from the parent in the above example. If you want a value to be accessible outside a method, then make it a class property. It's what they are for.

Comment: In short: no. Either you `return` the value, or you make it an instance property (`$this->v`).

Comment: `$v` does not exist outside of the `call()` function. It is a local variable. Read about [variables scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).